# Verify the figure gap between 2 numbers and a random number in PHP

Tags: php, random

I have a little problem with PHP. I create a little game in PHP, in which two players must choose a number, and the one who is closest wins.

**Here are the rules:**

> - Player 1 chooses the minimum number (to generate the random number to find) **CHECK**
> - Player 2 chooses the maximum number (to generate the random number to find) **CHECK**
> - The two players pick their numbers (between the minimum and maximum)
> - The player who is closest to the randomly generated number (between the minimum and maxium), win the game

**This is my script**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input name="min" type="number" placeholder="Min" />
    <input name="max" type="number" placeholder="Max" />
    <input name="player1" type="number" placeholder="player1" />
    <input name="player2" type="number" placeholder="player2" />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" />
</form>

<?php

    // Variables

    $min = $_POST['min'];
    $max = $_POST['max'];
    $player1 = $_POST['player1'];
    $player2 = $_POST['player2'];


    // Get Random Number

    function getRandomNumber($min, $max) {

        return mt_rand($min, $max);

    }


    // Submit Form

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        echo "The random number is " . getRandomNumber($min, $max) . "<br />";
        echo "Player 1: " . $player1 . "<br />";
        echo "Player 2: " . $player2 . "<br />";

    }

?>
```

Thank you in advance for your response.

Comment: Player 1 & Player 2 are sitting at the same computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No doubt you have figured th answer to your question but if not then maybe this might help.

```
$min = intval( $_POST['min'] );
$max = intval( $_POST['max'] );

$player1 = intval( $_POST['player1'] );
$player2 = intval( $_POST['player2'] );

function getRandomNumber( $min, $max ) {
    return mt_rand($min, $max);
}


if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {

    $random=getRandomNumber( $min, $max );

    $results=array();
    $results['player1']=abs( $random-$player1 );
    $results['player2']=abs( $random-$player2 );

    $low=min( $results );
    $high=max( $results );
    $winner=array_search( $low, $results );
    $loser=array_search( $high, $results );



    if( $low!==$high ){
        echo ucfirst( $winner ).' wins by guessing '.$_POST[ $winner ].' and being '.$low.' away from the random number of '.$random.'. 
            '.ucfirst( $loser ).' lost by guessing '.$_POST[ $loser ].' which was '.$high.' from the designated random number...';
    } else {
        echo 'It\'s a draw!!! Both players guessed '.$_POST[ $winner ].' which is '.$low.' away from the target of '.$random;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work without some sort of persistent data.  You have a server that will have a session going for each user.  But you cannot share the session with some other user without some intermediate shaking hands.

I suggest posting the inputs to a database.  The database must also hold the state of each player (if they have submitted or not).

I further suggest that you use JavaScript with AJAX to control each client side, and poll the server for statuses.

Comment: Sure, it's juste a quick demo for test directly ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// Variables

$min = $_POST['min'];
$max = $_POST['max'];
$player1 = $_POST['player1'];
$player2 = $_POST['player2'];


// Get Random Number

function getRandomNumber($min, $max) {

    return mt_rand($min, $max);

}


// Submit Form

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $rd =  getRandomNumber($min, $max);
    $p1 = $player1 - $rd;
    $p2 = $player2 - $rd;
    echo "The random number is " . $rd . "<br />";
    echo "Player 1: " . $player1 . "<br />";
    echo "Player 2: " . $player2 . "<br />";
    if($p1<$p2){
         echo "Player 1 wins!";

   }else{
        echo "Player2 wins!";
   }
}

?>
```